# Adding css animation duration to different elements using nth-child

Tags: css, css-animations

I have some text in an `<h3>` tag which I've split over 3 lines. I'm running a `translateY` animation and having the text slide up reveal. This is all working fine. I'm trying to adjust the animation duration of each line of text. I've tried using :nth-child selector for each line and then adding

```
animation-duration: 5s for line 1
animation-duration: 10s for line 2
animation-duration: 15s for line 3
```

But it's not working. It seems the parent animation-duration is always taking over or it's using the animation duration for the first nth-child. Any ideas why?

Here's the code i've got so far

```css
   h3 {
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      text-align: left;
      line-height: normal;
      color: #636363;
    }
    h3 span {
      display: block;
    }
    h3 > span {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    h3 > span > span {
       position: relative;
       animation-name: reveal-up;
       animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
    }
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(1) {
       animation-duration: 5s !important;
    }
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(2) {
      animation-duration: 10s !important;
    }
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(3) {
      animation-duration: 15s !important;
    }

    @keyframes reveal-up {
      from { transform: translateY(100%); }
      to {transform: translateY(0); }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <h3>
          <span><span>Zephex® 152a: reducing</span></span>
          <span><span>the carbon footprint of</span></span>
          <span><span>asthma inhalers</span></span>
      </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You are counting the children on the wrong level. Each of your `h3 > span` elements only _has_ one single child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```css
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(1) {
       animation-duration: 5s !important;
    }
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(2) {
      animation-duration: 10s !important;
    }
    h3 > span > span:nth-child(3) {
      animation-duration: 15s !important;
    }
```

to

```css
    h3 > span:nth-child(1) > span {
       animation-duration: 5s !important;
    }
    h3 > span:nth-child(2) > span {
      animation-duration: 10s !important;
    }
    h3 > span:nth-child(3) > span {
      animation-duration: 15s !important;
    }
```

Comment: And use just one  `<span>`

Answer (score 1):

may be this is what you are looking for

```css
 

h3 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: left;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #636363;
}
h3 span {
  display: block;
}
h3 span {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h3 span span {
   position: relative;
   animation-name: reveal-up;
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
h3 span span:nth-child(1) {
   animation-duration: 5s !important;
}
h3 span span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-duration: 10s !important;
}
h3 span span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-duration: 15s !important;
}

@keyframes reveal-up {
  from { transform: translateY(100%); }
  to {transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h3>
      <span><span>Zephex® 152a: reducing</span></span>
      <span><span>the carbon footprint of</span></span>
      <span><span>asthma inhalers</span></span>
  </h3>
</div>
```